# $\alpha = \pi^6 + 5 \pi^3 -1 $ is algebraic or transcendent over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

$\alpha = \pi^6 + 5 \pi^3 -1 $ is algebraic or transcendent over $\mathbb{Q}$? I tried, but I couldn't. can anybody help me?

Comment: If $P$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients such that $P(\alpha)=0$, then $Q(x)=P(x^6+5x^3-1)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients such that $Q(\pi)=0$.

Comment: Absolutely clear that it is trascendent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is algebraic ofver $\Bbb Q$, then $\pi$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ and hence also over $\Bbb Q$. But we know that $\pi$ is transcendental.